# How to find consecutive rows, that an employee is 'Absent'?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table name employee. which has 4 columns: id, name, statuse and date_present.

The date_present column contains all the dates an employee is present and absent. i need to write a query to find if any employee is continuously absent for more than 3 days.

```
id | name | statuse | date_presnet
1  | khan | present | 2016-12-1
2  | jan  | present | 2016-12-2
3  | Kiran| absent  | 2016-12-3
4  | jan  | absent  | 2016-12-4
4  | jan  | absent  | 2016-12-5
4  | jan  | absent  | 2016-12-6
```

Comment: was "I need it Urgent" part of the question?

Comment: I would like to suggest you to check the 3 consecutive absents in PHP or programming language instead of doing in MySQL Query.

Comment: I just need it in Mysql or postrgesql

Comment: Perhaps typing faster will help with the urgency of the problem.

Comment: postgressql has window functions and mysql does not and the answer will be very different based on that  so which database are you using?

Comment: if it's in postgresql it will be my pleasure.

Comment: This is the second post for the OP.  The downvotes and closes are not very welcoming.  Yes, I admit that the "urgent" part was a bit presumptuous (so I removed it).  And, the OP could show a sample query -- but most questions don't have them.  It really better to educate the OP rather than just downvoting or voting to close.  The question itself is reasonable.

Comment: @GordonLinoff you might recall the reason for upvotes. If you hover over the arrow it suggests "It shows research effort, useful, and clear". It does not mean "I just answered it and I want to prop it up" as you alleged do often. As the rest of us try to keep the stack a clean place. For what it's worth, I didn't downvote or vote to close. But I close 40 to 50 a day.

Answer (score 0):

One approach in MySQL (or really in any database) is to use `join` to connect records to the next date:

```
select t.*
from t join
     t t2
     on t2.id = t1.id and
        t2.date = date_add(t1.date, interval 1 day) and
        t2.status = 'absent' and t.status = 'absent' join
     t t3
     on t3.id = t1.id and
        t3.date = date_add(t1.date, interval 2 day) and
        t3.status = 'absent' ;
```